# How to continuously get mails using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently working on Microsoft Graph API and would like to get mails for multiple users in the tenant. I am currently able to use `filter` to get mails from certain period of time programatically and it works fine !

However, I'd like to know if there is any way that we can setup a constant polling mechanism in Graph API which scales out dynamically according to the users.

For Example :- Let us assume that there are 5 users in a tenant and a new user is added, then I'd like the code/poller to scale out dynamically and get all mails for the users in all their corresponding folders without getting redundant mails or previously received mails.

Comment: Basically what you want is a mailing service. Can you use the IMAP or POP3 mail services directly instead of Microsoft Graph? If you have to use Microsoft Graph, you can take a look at Microsoft Graph Notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Comment: Yes i agree with @nrofis. If you want to use Microsoft Graph then get it started with Graph Notifications/webhooks. It will suit your scenario; also consider checking the delta query changes too.